# Extracting from CSV file knowing row and column number on command line

Tags: csv, extract, data-analysis

I have a CSV file and I want to extract the element in the first row and 3rd column. How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would load the CSV in a matrix and then take the relevant row/column; of course, you could ignore the non-relevant element while loading the CSV. How to do the aforementioned has already been answered e.g.
[How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c)